# What style questions should I ask potential graduate students interviewing for positions in my lab?

Tags: professorship, interview

As a converse to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/353/what-are-some-good-questions-to-ask-current-graduate-students-when-visiting-scho), as a professor, I find it difficult to conduct a useful interview. **What types of questions should I ask which would give me a good idea as to how (1) productive and (2) self-sustaining of a student the interviewee may be?** If different questions are required for each parameter, please mention that in your answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I underwent an interview recently from a prospective adviser, and I found the questions he asked of me to be pretty insightful - hence I'm sharing them here.

- Why do you want to pursue research in this specific area?

  This would highlight the candidate's motivation in wanting to do research in a particular field - and would also tell the professor more about the candidate's exposure to this area.
- What made you apply to this lab/university, as a continuation of the previous question?

  The answer would tell you whether the applicant had simply browsed the rankings list of universities, or did he/she actually go through the research publications of the lab - and the application was done due to an intersection of the two!
- What would you like to be doing post Ph.D.?

  There is no "right" answer to this, but it also tells a lot about the candidate's motivation in pursuing a PhD.
- Finally, you can ask the candidate to discuss any problem that he is familiar with in that field - doesn't have to be anything fancy/complicated, but that would serve to highlight the clarity of the applicant's reasoning, communication skills, and level of exposure to the field.

Comment: I wish I could mark both yours and @aeismail correct... both excellent answers!

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the questions that shan23 has mentioned, I ask candidates for my group a few other questions:

- *What kind of advising style do they like? How "hands-on" or "hands-off" do they want me to be?* If they want someone whose style is vastly different from mine, that's going to be a problem.
- *What is your preferred working environment? (When?, Where?, etc.)* I just want to get a sense of what they're going to be like to work with.
- *What kinds of projects do they like?* Do they want a methodology-driven project, or are they more interested in applications.
- *Have you spoken with members of my group?* I want future group members to have an interest in who they'll be working with.

Answer (score 5):

Ask them about their ***expectations*** out of their coming 3-5 years as a grad student!

I find that a significant portion of the frustration that I (and those others around me) have experienced is due to s*evere disparity between expectations and reality*. Note that this is as much for the benefit of the prospective student as it is for you as the PI.

Specifically things to consider regarding expectations:

- **The amount and style of supervision the student expects.** My expectation was that I would "do science" and not "paperwork", in reality my PI knew less about the paperwork then I did, so I typically ended up needing to do a bunch of paperwork regarding employment (like salary raises, progress reports etc) and always late too...
- **The abundance and lack of relevant competencies in the lab, for that proposed project.** I was confident that the lack of computational competency at our lab wasn't gonna be a problem for me. I couldn't be more wrong..
- **The workplace interaction with colleagues.** I was under the impression that we'd be a team of intellectuals, tackling problems together, from our own angles. Again I was dead-wrong... Here, everyone's buried under their own pile of... Similarly, I can imagine that if the student expects to be a lone-wolf, forced team-work might be frustrating in the long run.
- **How to handle getting stuck/frustrated.** This is quite self-explanatory I guess..

Answer (score 3):

This is my favorite question to ask in interviews:

*Can you tell me about a problem you encountered in the laboratory, and the process you went through to troubleshoot it?*

Answer (score 1):

I think a good general question to ask is what motivates them to do their research. The answer should give you a good idea at least for the latter and depending on the level of detail maybe also for the former.