# What to do when visiting a lab or a university for prospective application?

Tags: phd, postdocs, job, career-path

In his famous and interesting article ["Ten Simple Rules for Selecting a Postdoctoral Position"](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pcbi.0020121), author Philippe Bourne states, in the 2nd point:

> Rule 2: Select a Laboratory That Suits Your Work and Lifestyle
>
> If at all possible, visit the laboratory before making a decision.
>   [...]

I think that is definitively a good advice, not only for Post-Doc applicants, but for all applicants in general. But, **what is the best way to arrange a lab visit?**

What to do when you're there?

Whom to speak to?
What to ask?
What to do?

Comment: This question is mostly answered by "[What are some good questions to ask current graduate students when visiting schools?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/353/what-are-some-good-questions-to-ask-current-graduate-students-when-visiting-scho)".

Comment: The question of how to arrange a visit is a different issue.

Comment: Is this for prospective Ph.D students or prospective postdocs ?

Comment: @Suresh for both... what do you advice in the two cases?

Answer (score 3):

Two options I can think of:

1. Simply email the professor and arrange a visit.
2. Some programs will have lab tours during the recruitment/orientation programs, so you can try to arrange to meet the professor on that visit.