# How to prepare for a phone interview with a prospective advisor?

Tags: graduate-admissions, advisor, interview

I sent my initial inquiry email to a prospective advisor on Wednesday with a brief description of my background and my interest in his research (I talked about one of his papers). He emailed me back the next day and seemed very interested in my background and the fact that I took time to research him, and requested more information from me (i.e., marks, certain courses). I sent him the requested information and he emailed me back yesterday morning saying he’s sure I will be accepted into their program and asked me various questions regarding funding (i.e., grants) and plans for the future.

We then scheduled a phone call for this afternoon. I’m not sure what the call will entail, but what are some things I should do to prepare? What are some questions I should ask?

(I am not asking this question at the last minute because I got lazy. My email interactions happened with him very fast. I was usually told it takes prospective advisors weeks to get back to students.)

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17192/what-are-the-right-questions-to-ask-professors-at-a-visit-day-for-prospective/17197#17197

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in joining the group, then you should be able to show that you've done a little bit of prep work (which clearly you have, since you've talked about his papers).

Questions I'd like prospective students to ask me include:

- What projects do you have upcoming?
- What is your advising style like?
- What are your expectations for graduating students?
- Could I talk with some of your graduate students/postdocs?